# R2Mail2 - GnuPG encrypting email to a different email address than in the public key

Tags: email, encryption

I have a friend's public key with the associated email address bla@bla.com. I would like to use the key to send an encrypted email to the email address not@not.com.

Is this possible in R2Mail2 for Android? I can in Thunderbird/Enigmail, but it doesn't seem possible in R2Mail2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for your problem. Had the same as well. Searched a long time to get my Keys to the Android phone.

I work with OSX. There is a tutorial how to Export the keys it seems to be a matter of  Key and Certificate conversion. Hope that helps:

http://hackonadime.blogspot.de/2012/03/securing-your-mobile-email-thunderbird.html

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (please [edit] your question and do so). Otherwise your question ceases to be helpful in case the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt your message to any public key(s). I also recommend encrypt-to-self. Then send it as an attachment to any address.

Answer (score 0):

No thats not possible within R2Mail2 at the moment. As soon I have time I will implement an option where you can link additional email addressee to an public key.

regards
stefan